# RAID5 does not spindown after grow (ext4lazyinit)

Tags: hard-drive, raid, ext4, mdadm, raid-5

I had a RAID5 array consisting of 3x5TB disks assembled using `mdadm`. On top of that, I created a `LUKS/dmcrypt` encryption layer and formatted the encrypted device with `ext4`. I want the disks to spin down in case of inactivity.

Everything worked fine for several months, the disks were spinning down after a minute of inactivity. Now, I added a fourth 5TB disk of the same kind to the array by `sudo mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1`, then I grew the array onto that disk (`mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=4`), and finally grew the filesystem with `sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/raid5` and `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/raid5`.

No errors occured, and the array is now 5TB larger. But the disks are not spinning down anymore. The machine runs 24/7, is not using the disks, but despite waiting a couple of days, the disks are still running all the time.

`iotop` shows frequent occurences of `ext4lazyinit`, which pops up for less then a second every few seconds. I didn't notice that before growing the filesystem. So probably it's that tasks keeping the disks awake? But how can I force `ext4lazyinit` to complete it's task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ext4lazyinit` is doing exactly what it says - it's initializing the rest of the filesystem in a lazy way. It does this to give the apperance of quickly producing a filesystem. As you have noticed, it's going to try to impact the performance of your system as little as possible, and this means it's going to take a long time to complete.

The first option is to wait it out - it'll stop eventually, and your disks should return to idle.

---

Another option is to unmount the filesystem, and temorarily mount it with `-o init_itable=0`, forcing the lazy init to be more proactive, but performance will suffer. The default value is 10, so if performance is important in the meantime,
 perhaps try values in between. ([ref](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt))

> ```
> init_itable=n    The lazy itable init code will wait n times the number of milliseconds
>                  it took to zero out the previous block group's inode table. This
>                  minimizes the impact on the system performance while file system's
>                  inode table is being initialized.
> ```

---

A third option is do disable the itable initialization - though in my opinion, this is a bad option, especially for a filesystem that is in production and presumably has important data on it (that's why you're using a RAID, right?)

You can do this with the `noinit_itable` option:

> ```
> noinit_itable     Do not initialize any uninitialized inode table blocks in the
>                   background. This feature may be used by installation CD's so that the
>                   install process can complete as quickly as possible; the inode table 
>                   initialization process would then be deferred until the next time the
>                   file system is unmounted.
> ```

---

Edit: Estimations on duration.

Bear in mind that disks have a write performance of ~110-120MB/s... You're running an array, so in an ideal world will see an improvement to ~330-360MB/s (`110 * (n - 1)`). I've also seen RAID5 run *much* slower (~40MB/s over 8 disks with a RAID controller - painful).

With an estimated 110MB/s you're looking at around 12 hours for a full one-disk 5TB init.

Comment: As I said, the array is idle most of the time, so performance is not an issue. But data integrity is, as you already guessed. So I tried with `init_itable=0`, which at least causes `ext4lazyinit` to be active with 100% disk usage most of the time. So I'll see if it finishes it's job by tomorrow.

Comment: good stuff - I've updated to include an estimate for how long you could expect this to go on for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the estimations - it's already finished! The disks just spun down and everything is quiet again! I'm so glad that helped. Now I'll remount without `init_itable=0` and see if it stays that way. I guess it was much faster than your estimations because the filesystem is 60% used. Although I got much slower speeds, around 4MB/s (probably random reads/writes?)